# How to not trigger dependent builds of a scheduled build on teamcity when the last dependent build is green?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I have two build configurations:

```kotlin
val buildA = BuildA()
buildType(buildA)

val buildB = BuildB()
buildB.dependencies {
    snapshot(buildA) {
        onDependencyFailure = FailureAction.CANCEL
        onDependencyCancel = FailureAction.CANCEL
        reuseBuilds = ReuseBuilds.SUCCESSFUL
    }
    artifacts(buildA) {
        buildRule = lastSuccessful(branch = "master")
        artifactRules = "+:my-very-important-file"
    }
}
buildB.triggers {
    schedule {
        schedulingPolicy = cron {
            minutes = "12/30"
        }
        branchFilter = "+:<default>"
        triggerBuild = always()
        withPendingChangesOnly = false
    }
}
buildType(buildB)
```

I need `buildB` to be triggered on a scheduled basis, which works. Also, I need `buildB` to get access to the `my-very-important-file` generated as an artifact of `buildA`. However, generating that file requires hitting an API that has some throttling in place, limiting the number of API calls to a few per day. Furthermore, two subsequent builds of `buildA` generate the very same `my-very-important-file`, so there is no reason to re-run `buildA`. For those reasons, I need `buildA` to be called once, and only once, and then all scheduled builds `buildB` would use the file produced once by that `buildA`.

I thought the above configuration would achieve that, because I tell to reuse successful builds in the snapshot dependency definition, and also the artifact dependency is defined to use the last successful build of `buildA`. However, in practice, `buildA` gets triggered almost everytime `buildB` gets triggered.

What am I doing wrong?